# Ruby equivalent for Javascript's 'console.log(a,b)'

Tags: javascript, ruby

In JavaScript, `console.log` works like this:

```
$ node
> console.log(1,2) ; console.log(3,4)
1 2
3 4
```

In Ruby, I want to output the value of `a`, followed by a space, then the value of `b`, then following that a newline. Neither of these are satisfactory:

```
$ irb
2.4.1 :001 > print 1,2 ; print 3,4
1234 => nil 
2.4.1 :002 > puts 1,2 ; puts 3,4
1
2
3
4
 => nil
```

Am I out of luck without rolling my own?

Answer (score 6):

According to [the doc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Kernel.html#method-i-print), you have to override field separator and record separator.

```
$, = " "    # field separator
$\ = "\n"   # record separator
print 3, 5
3 5
nil
```

Comment: Thanks!  I can put that in my .irbrc if I like.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent would be

```
printf "%s %s\n", 1, 2
```

or

```
puts [1, 2].join(" ")
```

But you try to emulate javascript to show the contents of two variables on one line, I don't know about javascript but in Ruby two variables separated by a comma is an array. The real Ruby equivalent would be

```
p [1, 2]
```

or since you use irb

```
[1, 2]
```

In console.log you also see the line at which this code is executed, you can do that with __LINE__.
A very simple debugging you can achieve while executing a script is like this

```
var = "content"
[__FILE__, __LINE__, "var", var]
```

Like this you get the name of the file where the line resides in, the line number, the name of the variable and the contents. Call it a poor mans debugger or console.log if you like.

Answer (score 1):

> Ruby equivalent for Javascript's `console.log`

Conceptually, Ruby's [`Logger`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html) class comes close:

```
require 'logger'
logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

logger.info [1, 2]
logger.info [3, 4]
```

but its default output is quite different:

```
I, [2017-10-20T09:29:16.372886 #13107]  INFO -- : [1, 2]
I, [2017-10-20T09:29:16.372966 #13107]  INFO -- : [3, 4]
```

You could write a custom formatter:

```
class SimpleFormatter
  def call(severity, time, progname, msg)
    "%s\n" % msg2str(msg)
  end

  def msg2str(msg)
    case msg
    when String then msg
    when Array  then msg.map(&:inspect).join(' ')
    else msg.inspect
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
require 'logger'
logger = Logger.new(STDOUT, formatter: SimpleFormatter.new)

logger.info [1, 2]
logger.info [3, 4]
```

Output:

```
1 2
3 4
```

You could also take `severity` into account to [colorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) your output accordingly (so `logger.warn` prints in yellow, `logger.error` prints in red, etc.)